# mySQL query to get only display

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I wanted to ask one question as my query skills are not that great and I have been learning mySQL for the last week. This attachment I have shows what happens when I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM clothing, sizing WHERE id = "101";
```

You might notice that it produces the same id number, same name, same type, same brand_id,same price, and a lot of null values. Is there a query which I can run which only displays columns which do not have null values?

[image: t]

Comment: change it to WHERE id=101 AND NOT NULL IN (column1, column2, column3)

Comment: You are selecting data from two tables: `clothing` and `sizing`, but you are not binding them together. Maybe what you'll have to do is to [JOIN them together](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7877720/2752041) and then filter `NULL` results in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the rows that dont have null values in given columns, or you can use IFNULL.

```
IFNULL(yourColumn,0)
```

This will display 0 instead of Null, but beware that NULL and 0 is not the same thing.
Null is "nothing" / undefined, 0 is a numerical value.

You can have issues multiplying with NULL, so you can do for instance:

```
SELECT (numProducts * IFNULL(productPrice,0))
FROM ...
```

You can also use CASE or IF to select differenct colums and alias them :-)

External link to docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: I didnt see before now that you have two columns.
You have to join one colum to the other.

If you use a natural join and it's missing in one of the tables, it will effectivly hide that row. If you use an outer join (or inner), you can choose to display the "mother" table. Eg. like if you wish to display customers, even if they have no orders, you can consider an outer join.

Since you have clothing and sizing, I guess you will use a natural join. (Since it doesent exist, if it doesent exist in that size?). Just my guess, it's hard to view on the small picture :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes above solutions will work only if that column has default value set to null,if its not set then you need to check blank ,i mean to say IFNULL(productPrice,0) will not work you need to do as below,

SELECT (numProducts * IF(productPrice='',0,productPrice))
FROM ...

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking about two problems that I will address separately in this answer.

### 1 - More than one record is returned

You should follow [mathielo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000194/mysql-query-to-get-only-display#comment33344249_22000194) and [Olavxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000194/mysql-query-to-get-only-display#comment33344443_22000355)'s comments regarding the use of `JOIN`.

The query as shown in your question is a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) between your tables `clothing` and `sizing`. What the query is basically asking is "I want only the record with `id` 101 in one of the table, as well as *all* the records in the other table".

Judging by the rest of your question, this is not what you want. So I take it there is a relationship between rows in `clothing` and `sizing`. I will assume that a clothing can only have one size, and that this relationship is represented by a foreign key to `sizing`. Here the minimum the tables should contain for that to work (I do not reuse your model because from the details in the question I can only guess, not know, what your exact table model is):

```
clothing:
    id: primary key
    size_id: foreign key to sizing

sizing:
    size_id: primary key
```

As a consequence, the following query should return all records corresponding to the selected clothing and associated size:

```
SELECT *
FROM     clothing AS c
    JOIN sizing AS s ON c.size_id = s.size_id
WHERE c.id = 101
```

Your relationship between your two tables may actually be different from what I have just modeled. If that is the case, I still hope the above example is enough to get you started in the right direction.

### 2 - Lots of NULL values

This part of the question needs to be precised. Is it that you do not want the records with NULL values for some columns to be returned, or is it that you just do not want to get the content of these columns? Or maybe you want to use a default value?

If it is the records you want to filter out, you should add `<column> IS NOT NULL` conditions in your `WHERE` clause. One for each of the columns you are interested in.

If it is the columns you do not want to get, do not use `SELECT *` but instead explicitely list the columns you want, for example:

```
SELECT id, name, price FROM clothing
```

If it is about using a default value instead, you need to use `IF` in the `SELECT` clause as in [Supriya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22013901/2069806). Another example:

```
SELECT name, size, IF(shoulder IS NULL, 'Default', shoulder)
FROM clothing
```